# Stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to create a stacked chart using ggplot2 and geom_bar.

Here is my source data:

```
Rank F1     F2     F3
1    500    250    50
2    400    100    30
3    300    155    100
4    200    90     10
```

I want a stacked chart where x is the rank and y is the values in F1, F2, F3.

```
# Getting Source Data
  sample.data <- read.csv('sample.data.csv')

# Plot Chart
  c <- ggplot(sample.data, aes(x = sample.data$Rank, y = sample.data$F1))
  c + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

This is as far as i can get. I'm not sure of how I can stack the rest of the field values.

Maybe my data.frame is not in a good format?

Comment: this question is asked on a daily basis

Comment: @user2209016 Check out the documentation: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html. It answers a lot of common questions.

Comment: In my opinon, the link to the documentation above is a poor place to begin learning ggplot. For example, knowing that "The aesthetic mapping...only needs to be set at the layer level if you are overriding the plot defaults" is not useful to a beginner. I have found the cookbook webpages to be way more accessible.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You said :

> Maybe my data.frame is not in a good format?

Yes this is true. Your data is in the **wide** format  You need to put it in the **long** format. Generally speaking, long format is better for **variables comparison**.

Using `reshape2` for example , you do this using `melt`:

```
dat.m <- melt(dat,id.vars = "Rank") ## just melt(dat) should work
```

Then you get your barplot:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = Rank, y = value,fill=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

But using `lattice` and `barchart` smart formula notation , you don't need to reshape your data , just do this:

```
barchart(F1+F2+F3~Rank,data=dat)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped along with all the other answers. Generally do you like to use lattice over ggplot2?

Comment: Good question. It short, `ggeplot2` aes is unbeatable (binding data to plot features) but sometimes I find lattice `panel` very helpful and easier to integrate with `grid` package than `ggplot2`

Comment: @CMichael No. The OP was about `ggplot2`, so it is normal that all the answers pointed `ggplot2` not `lattice`. But I admit that there are more questions about `ggplot2` than ``lattice`

Answer (score 44):

You need to transform your data to long format and shouldn't use `$` inside `aes`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="Rank F1     F2     F3
1    500    250    50
2    400    100    30
3    300    155    100
4    200    90     10", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF1 <- melt(DF, id.var="Rank")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Building on Roland's answer, using `tidyr` to reshape the data from wide to long:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(text="Rank F1     F2     F3
1    500    250    50
2    400    100    30
3    300    155    100
4    200    90     10", header=TRUE)

df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, F1:F3) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will need to `melt` your dataframe to get it into the so-called long format:

```
require(reshape2)
sample.data.M <- melt(sample.data)
```

Now your field values are represented by their own rows and identified through the variable column. This can now be leveraged within the ggplot aesthetics:

```
require(ggplot2)
c <- ggplot(sample.data.M, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable))
c + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Instead of stacking you may also be interested in showing multiple plots using facets:

```
c <- ggplot(sample.data.M, aes(x = Rank, y = value))
c + facet_wrap(~ variable) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```