# How to make a barplot in ggplot2 with both horizontal and vertical stacked bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

My data frame is this one:

```
data <- data.frame("GROUP"= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), "C1_PERCENTAGE" = c(0, 10 ,22, 34, 37, 18, 24, 13), "C2_PERCENTAGE"=c(0, 8, 20, 24, 23, 11, 18, 9))
```

I want to produce a bar plot with the bars stacked horizontally based on `GROUP`so that there will be three groups of bars horizontally. And vertically, I want to stack the bars based `C1_PERCENTAGE` and `C2_PERCENTAGE`.

I want to use ggplot2. I used base graphics but this is for C1_PERCENTAGE only.

```
barplot(data$C1_PERCENTAGE, col = as.factor(data$GROUP)
```

[image]

This gives plot for `C1_PERCENTAGE`. I would like `C2_PERCENTAGE` also alongside these bars.

Comment: Is this not [tiles plot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html)?

Comment: Perhaps `barplot("colnames<-"(t(data)[-1,], data[,1]), beside=TRUE)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 - Stacked Bar Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236229/ggplot2-stacked-bar-chart)

Comment: this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236229/ggplot2-stacked-bar-chart should be useful

Comment: This is not what I want. Please see the edit

Comment: Are you after something more like [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar-16.png)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two different variants.

First we need to prepare the data, (a) add id, (b) reshape to long format.

**prepare data**

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(
  "id" = 1:24,
  "GROUP" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  "C1_PERCENTAGE" = c(0, 10 ,22, 34, 37, 18, 24, 13),
  "C2_PERCENTAGE"=c(0, 8, 20, 24, 23, 11, 18, 9)
  )
ld <- melt(d, id.vars = c("id", "GROUP"))
```

**stacked bar chart**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ld, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

**facetted bar chart**

```
ggplot(ld, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = factor(GROUP))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: @technOslerphile Thank you for accepting my answer - but which of the two variants finally did answer your question / meet your requirement. Thank you.

Comment: Had to edit the code for the facetted bar chart to match the graph