# Multiple columns on x-axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm quite new to R, and there has been a question similar to mine asked before, however it doesn't quite get to what I need.

I have a table as follows:

[image]

I wish to plot the `Value,` and `Threshold` alongside each other on the X-axis for each metric, so effectively, I will have three pairs of plots on the X-axis. I have attempted to use `reshape2` and `ggplot2` for this as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(msi, id.vars="Average Metric Value (Abbr)")
# I get an error message, but the output seems ok.

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x="Average Metric Value (Abbr)", y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

The output graph is as follows:

[image]

I'm sure I can work out how to separate each of the three pairs later, but as you can see, I don't have the metric names for each of the three pairs along the x-axis, and I am missing the first "Value" bar, presumably because it equals the same as the second and I am only getting unique values plotted.

How do I get around that and have the names of each metric beneath each pairs of values?

Comment: Use backquotes or place it in `aes_string`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236229/stacked-bar-chart)

Comment: Please don't remove your data and use an image link...

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode  I didn't downvote, but this might be a helpful read. replace "code" with "data"

Comment: Thank you Dan and PoGibas. My apologies for any confusion. I haven't used this much and am still getting the hang of it!  Thank you also Akrun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by placing inside the `aes_string` or use `backquotes` in the `aes` for those columns that have spaces in its names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(msi, variable, value, Value:Threshold) %>%
        ggplot(., aes(x= `Average Metric Value (Abbr)`, 
                      y=value,
                      fill=variable)) +
            geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I get the following error however: > ggplot(df, aes_string(x="Average Metric Value (Abbr)", y="value", fill="variable")) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:9: unexpected symbol
1: Average Metric
                     ^

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry, I haven't used this much and missed most of your answer! Thank you kindly!