# Plot stacked bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

This is not a duplicate question, but it is based on: [Stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236229/stacked-bar-chart)

I am trying to use the accepted answer by agstudy.
I have the following dataframe:

```
  types   c1      c2  c3  c4   c5  c6
       A   20     2   6   1    16  1
       B   15     1   7   1    7   1
       C   7      5   3   0    8   3
       D   5      7   4   7    6   4
       F   6      6   6   2    5   6
       E   17     8   2   3    4   9


tbl<-melt(tbl,id.vars="types")
ggplot(tbl,aes(x=types,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

This is a simple way to create a stacked bar chart. I originally had an issue about stacking cause of the `melt()`.

My issue comes with stacking the data to get all the values on top of each in one column per row. It would not stack because I had the wrong names and I did not understand the output of melt. But now that I do understand the melt function, it splits up the data and groups it over the `id.vars.` by doing so you can create a graph, such that  the fill aspect of the graph will be the variable where it fills in the bar with the values in the `value` column from `melt`. This is interpreted by R as a stacked bar chart.

Comment: . Have you changed the column names in the `melt` output?  In the `ggplot` a different object is used `trans_tbl`.  By default, the `melt` returns the column names as value and variable (if you haven't changed those names).  If you look at `?reshape2::melt` `melt(data, ..., na.rm = FALSE, value.name = "value")`

Comment: You can change the column names with `reshape2::melt(tbl, id.var = "types", variable.name = "buys", value.name = "total")`

Comment: What do you mean change the columns in the melt output?

Comment: I meant change the column names that you want in the long format.  By default, it is `variable` and `value`

Comment: I would prefer to use the defult method instead of changing the column names

Comment: unable  to reproduce, tbl doesn't have total ,buys, loans, lbs, free, pro, und columns which are used in your code

Comment: @TCZhang sorry, fixed.

Comment: Have you looked at your data after melting? You don't have columns named `total` or `c1`. In a `ggplot` `aes` function, you're mapping variables that are in your data to aesthetics such as x position or fill color, so `y = value` means that y values are set in the plot based on the `value` column of your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `melt` by default changes the 'wide' format to 'long' format and create two columns 'variable' and 'value' for the column names and the values corresponding to that columns in the 'wide' format accordingly.  The usage, according to `?reshape2::melt` is

> melt(data, ..., na.rm = FALSE, value.name = "value")

We could change the `value.name` and `variable.name` to different names (if needed).

```
newtbl <- reshape2::melt(tbl, id.var = "types")
```

It is better to have a look at the data before doing the plotting with either `head`

```
head(newtbl, 2)
#   types variable value
#1     A       c1    20
#2     B       c1    15
```

or `names` (or `colnames` - here it is a `data.frame`, so `names` would work as well)

```
names(newtbl) 
#[1] "types"    "variable" "value"
```

or to check the structure with `str`

```
str(newtbl)
#'data.frame':  36 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ types   : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
# $ variable: Factor w/ 6 levels "c1","c2","c3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
# $ value   : int  20 15 7 5 6 17 2 1 5 7 ...
```

In the other post, they used exactly these column names as argument in the `ggplot`

```
ggplot(newtbl,aes(x=types,y=value,fill=variable)) +
                     geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Comment: any luck with the barchart function? I have reshape2 loaded, but now it can't find the function barchart.

Comment: @JackArmstrong Do you mean `barplot` ? There is no function named barchart in base R.

Comment: at the end of agstudy's answer it seems that he concatenates the variables to be stacked in a way. He uses the function barchart, not barplot.

Comment: @JackArmstrong OK, that answer uses the lattice package so you need `library(lattice)` to get `barchart`.

Comment: Sorry still not understanding how to stack them. The barchart shows up, but sums every element across the row.

Comment: @JackArmstrong  Siorry, I am not following the comment

Comment: Using the above method, I get a barchart with the columns as totals and not broken down by each c1, c2, c3, etc. So for in the A column I should have 20 of c1, 2 of c2, etc. Will update above with what I have.

Comment: I did. see above.

Comment: Do you want to use `barplot` or `barchart`?

Comment: @JackArmstrong  If i use the `barchart` `barchart(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 +c5 + c6 ~ types, tbl)`, I get A 20 as in the data\