# ggplot bar chart of only the most freq repeated data

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a given data with below structure, how is possible to plot the freq chart of only most frequent day of week for each Names instead of all with ggplot? (For example, if name FIX011 has most day of week as Monday, just plot the Monday values for FIX011 and so on).

```
Column1 Name    Day of week "week Number"
1       BLA085  Friday      44
2       SNA101  Wednesday   45
3       BLA201  Thursday    42
4       BLA085  Wednesday   33
5       BLA085  Friday      40
6       KLO055  Friday      44
7       TAS087  Monday      35
8       AMB024  Tuesday     33
9   HOM012  Friday      35
10  COM388  Tuesday     41
11  SWA017  Tuesday     39
12  PIN087  Monday      32
13  HAR422  Wednesday   38
14  RYE001  Friday      40
15  FIX011  Friday      34
16  CAR273  Tuesday     43
17  PAS004  Wednesday   40
18  OSR001  Thursday    44
19  MUM001  Wednesday   35
20  PEE043  Thursday    39
21  SAN126  Monday      44
22  COL059  Monday      37
23  HYC001  Tuesday     43
24  OAS003  Monday      35
25  TOU023  Thursday    44
26  CYC010  Thursday    33
27  WHI101  Monday      31
28  TOR001  Wednesday   40
29  3MA001  Tuesday     41
30  HUM048  Friday      44
31  PEE045  Wednesday   43
32  WHI004  Friday      43
33  SCO026  Friday      43
34  RAI020  Thursday    42
35  BRU002  Wednesday   42
36  SID001  Monday      38
37  SID001  Tuesday     44
38  PIN087  Tuesday     34
39  DYM013  Wednesday   47
40  PAS001  Thursday    35
41  THR027  Thursday    43
42  WAG001  Monday      37
43  COO003  Thursday    40
44  DEL113  Friday      33
45  PAC140  Tuesday     39
46  SID001  Tuesday     39
47  KAR001  Thursday    43
48  COM388  Tuesday     42
49  FRE001  Monday      41
50  SWA017  Wednesday   43
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have correctly understood your question.

But first, to find the msot frequent day for each `Name`, you can use `dplyr` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
d <- df %>% group_by(Name, Day_of_week) %>% count(Day_of_week) %>% summarise(Max_Freq = n) %>% arrange(desc(Max_Freq))

# A tibble: 47 x 3
# Groups:   Name [43]
   Name   Day_of_week Max_Freq
   <chr>  <chr>          <int>
 1 BLA085 Friday             2
 2 COM388 Tuesday            2
 3 SID001 Tuesday            2
 4 3MA001 Tuesday            1
 5 AMB024 Tuesday            1
 6 BLA085 Wednesday          1
 7 BLA201 Thursday           1
 8 BRU002 Wednesday          1
 9 CAR273 Tuesday            1
10 COL059 Monday             1
# … with 37 more rows
```

Then, if you want to plot the max frequency of the day for each `Name` in ggplot, you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = Name, y = Max_Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Day_of_week, y = Max_Freq*1.7), angle = 90)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))+
  ylim(0,3.7)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ? If not, can you clarify what is the expected output ?

Comment: Thanks. I want the x axis to be week days and week numbers instead of the Names. So I know in each week and day I had most frequent value of Names in total.

Comment: One more thing, in the  d date frame you created, I just want to plot tho top value for each Name in the "Max_Freq" column to be plotted. For example, if for Name "BLA085" the most freq day is Friday, I want to filler out "Fridays" in the raw data and plot only Fridays for that Name.

Comment: But in your example, a single week day associated to a single Name is not associated by a single week number. For example for BLA085, Friday has either the number 44 (line 1) or 40 (line5). How are you dealing with that ?

Comment: Ok. So I have 18 weeks, So it appears on week 44 and week 40 as Friday then.

Comment: Ok, so how are you plotting that ? Can you make a drawing ?

Comment: Put simply, I want to know most frequent day of  week in last 18 weeks for each Name and plot them all together.

Comment: In this format:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280486/convert-day-number-to-day-and-week-name-in-bar-plot-x-axis-in-r