# stacked barchart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this:

```
  app_id <- seq(1,10,1)
  approved <- c(0,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0)
  week <- as.Date(c('2019-11-18','2019-11-18','2019-11-18','2019-11-25','2019-12-02','2019-12-02','2019-12-09','2019-12-09','2019-12-09','2019-12-09'))
  data <- data.frame(app_id,approved,week)
```

I would like to have a stacked barchart with `week` on x axis and `count of app_id` on y axis stacked by `approved` (so 3 colors)

How do I do that? Many thanks!

Comment: see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236229/stacked-bar-chart)

Comment: What have you tried so far? The ggplot docs have lots of examples and link to tutorials

Comment: @camille Yes I reset the order of the factor by adding `levels = c(you preferred order)` in `factor()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data %>%
    group_by(approved, week) %>%
    summarise(aggValue = n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(week, aggValue, fill = factor(approved))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! And how do I make `approved = 1` on the bottom?

Comment: `ggplot(aes(week, aggValue, fill = factor(approved, levels = c(0,2,1))))` ;)