# How to create a stacked bar chart in r with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

My data is:

```
positive <- c("21", "22", "33", "21", "27") ##Percentage
negative<- c("71", "77", "67", "79", "73")  ##Precentage 
sample <- c("Hr", "Fi", "We", "Pa", "Ki")
mydata <- data.frame(positive , negative, sample)
```

I want to create a stacked bar graph that shows positive and negative percentages for each category in the sample variable. I tried this:

```
ggplot(mydata) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = sample, fill = positive))
```

but did not wrok.
Sorry if the question looks basic. I started R a few weeks ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236229/stacked-bar-chart)

Comment: You should be more specific, particularly what exactly didn't work, but also what you want this to look like. Your code is just going to show counts of rows by sample—is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably serves your purpose:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% pivot_longer(cols = !sample, names_to = "status", values_to = "percentage") %>% 
 ggplot(aes(fill = status, x = sample, y = percentage)) + 
 geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to pivot your data to long format first (tidy format). Then, we can specify the x (`sample`), y (`value`), and fill (`name`) conditions.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  pivot_longer(-sample) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = name, y = value, x = sample)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `values_transform` to get numeric type and then using `geom_col` with `position_fill` and percentage features:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot)
library(scales)

mydata %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -sample,
    names_to = "status",
    values_to = "percentage", 
    values_transform = list(percentage = as.integer)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample, y=percentage, fill=status))+
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percentage),
            position = position_fill(vjust = .5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution ios the use of the side-by-side bars.

Sample data:

```
values <- c(21, 22, 33, 21, 27, -71, -77, -67, -79, -73) ##Percentage
sample <- factor(c("Hr", "Fi", "We", "Pa", "Ki"))
mydata <- data.frame(values, sample)
```

Sample code:

```
(ggplot(mydata, aes(x = sample, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity", position = position_stack(),
    color = "white", fill = "lightblue") +
  coord_flip())+
  labs(x="Sample",y="Percentage")+
  theme_bw()
```

Plot: [image]

Plot:

Sample code to show values:

```
(ggplot(mydata, aes(x = sample, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity", position = position_stack(),
    color = "white", fill = "lightblue"
  ) +
    geom_text(aes(label = values))+
  coord_flip())+
  labs(x="Sample",y="Percentage")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or if you want to color the positive and negative bars differently

```
(ggplot(mydata, aes(x = sample, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity", position = position_stack(),
    fill= ifelse(mydata$values < 0,"#ffcccb","lightblue")
  ) +
    geom_text(aes(label = values))+
  coord_flip())+
  labs(x="Sample",y="Percentage")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]