# In R how to make a stacked barplot sum to 1 with 3 columns in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization, stacked-chart

Here's my codes for dataframe:

```
position <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

freq_1 <- c(0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.9, 1)

freq_2 <- 1 - freq_1

mydata <- data.frame(position, freq_1, freq_2)
```

What kind of stacked barplot I want:

[image]

I have been googling for hours but could not find how to make the stacked barplot with my data.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `base` you could do:

```r
barplot(cbind(freq_1, freq_2) ~ position, data = mydata)
```

[image]

If you want to use `ggplot2`, see e.g.: [Stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236229/stacked-bar-chart)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!
The ggplot part gives me the graph I want!!!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! It was my first time to ask a question here so very helpful info to know the accept part.